# Create a select list in half-hour increments in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a `<select>` with `<option>` that creates a `list` with all of the times (12 hour time not 24 hour time) of the day in half hour increments. 
I tried using `xrange` and `cycle` to create a `list` with repeated numbers. I just can't get it. Of course I could manually write it out but what fun is that?
The end result would be:

`['12:00am', '12:30am','1:00am', '1:30am', '2:00am', '2:30am', '3:00am', '3:30am', '4:00am', '4:30am', '5:00am', '5:30am', '6:00am', '6:30am', '7:00am', '7:30am', '8:00am', '8:30am', '9:00am', '9:30am', '10:00am', '10:30am', '11:00am', '11:30am', '12:00am', '12:30am', '1:00pm', '1:30pm', '2:00pm', '2:30pm', '3:00pm', '3:30pm', '4:00pm', '4:30pm', '5:00pm', '5:30pm', '6:00pm', '6:30pm', '7:00pm', '7:30pm', '8:00pm', '8:30pm', '9:00pm', '9:30pm', '10:00pm', '10:30pm', '11:00pm', '11:30pm']`

Comment: To be certain, the end result you're looking for is a list such as `[12:00am, 12:30am, 1:00am]` etc.?

Comment: @PeterFoti: Yes exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
['%s:%s%s' % (h, m, ap) for ap in ('am', 'pm') for h in ([12] + list(range(1,12))) for m in ('00', '30')]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the times are in minutes, the following should work fine:

```
xrange(0, 1440, 30)
```

If they're supposed to be in some other format, this can generate them fine, and then be converted to whatever format you want.

Ex:

```
[(str(i / 60) if i / 60 > 9 else "0" + str(i / 60)) + ":" + (str(i % 60) if i % 60 > 9 else "0" + str(i % 60)) for i in xrange(0, 1440, 30)]
```

to give HH:MM

To get HH:MM[AM/PM], the following should work, if rather messily:

```
[((str(i / 60 % 12 + 1) if (i / 60 % 12 + 1) > 9 else "0" + str(i / 60 % 12 + 1)) + ":" + (str(i % 60) if i % 60 > 9 else "0" + str(i % 60)) + ("am" if i / 60 < 11 or i / 60 > 22 else "pm")) for i in xrange(0, 1440, 30)]
```

Edit: This will be in the right order, but won't start at the right place. To solve that, if the list formed from above is l, just take

```
l[-2:] + l[:-2]
```

Edit 2: Further, while this should work, it's really messy, so I'd probably put all of the conversion from minutes to date string in some function, and then just call that function in the list comprehension.

Comment: Im unable to vote at the moment, but thats some nifty code you've got there. Saved that for late, and will upvote when I can!

Comment: Very cool. I'm getting: `['01:00am', '01:30am', '02:00am', '02:30am', '03:00am', '03:30am', '04:00am', '04:30am', '05:00am', '05:30am', '06:00am', '06:30am', '07:00am', '07:30am', '08:00am', '08:30am', '09:00am', '09:30am', '10:00am', '10:30am', '11:00am', '11:30am', '12:00am', '12:30am', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm', 'pm']` Did I miss something?

Comment: No, I missed a few parentheses. I always forget that python's ternary operator associates in odd ways (Being used to the ?: of C). It should be fixed now. Oh, and I also seem to have the idea of which 12 is am and which is pm backwards. That'll take a bit of thinking, but I should have an edit to fix that shortly.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00 AM', '%I:%M %p')
>>> r = []
>>> r.append(s.strftime('%I:%M %p'))
>>> for i in range(30,60*24,30):
...     r.append((s+datetime.timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime('%I:%M %p'))
...
>>> r
['12:00 AM', '12:30 AM', '01:00 AM', '01:30 AM', '02:00 AM', '02:30 AM', '03:00 AM', '03:30 AM', '04:00 AM', '04:30 AM', '05:00 AM', '05:30 AM', '06:00 AM', '06:30 AM', '07:00 AM', '07:30 AM', '08:00 AM', '08:30 AM', '09:00 AM', '09:30 AM', '10:00 AM', '10:30 AM', '11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 PM', '12:30 PM', '01:00 PM', '01:30 PM', '02:00 PM', '02:30 PM', '03:00 PM', '03:30 PM', '04:00 PM', '04:30 PM', '05:00 PM', '05:30 PM', '06:00 PM', '06:30 PM', '07:00 PM', '07:30 PM', '08:00 PM', '08:30 PM', '09:00 PM', '09:30 PM', '10:00 PM', '10:30 PM', '11:00 PM', '11:30 PM']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for h in range(24):
    print '<option value="%i">%i:00</option>' % (h, h)
    print '<option value="%i">%i:30</option>' % (h, h)
```

Yeah (almost) repeating oneself with the :00 / :30 is bad, but it's easy.

*BAH, you edited the question to include arrays, I thought you wanted the HTML - ignore this*