# How to put hours of work into table?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have model:

```
class LoginLogout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    t_login = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    t_logout = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And I want to generate table like this:

```
2015-01-02

+-------+- USER1 -+- USER2 -+- USER3 -+
| 00:30 |         |         |         |
| 01:00 | ####### |         |         |
| 01:30 | ####### |         |         |
| 02:00 | ####### | ####### |         |
| 02:30 | ####### | ####### |         |
| 03:00 |         | ####### |         |
| 03:30 |         |         |         |
| 04:00 |         |         |         |
| 04:30 |         |         |         |
| 05:00 |         |         | ####### |
| 05:30 |         |         | ####### |
| 06:00 |         |         |         |
| 06:30 |         |         |         |
| [...] |         |         |         |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I can generate hours (thanks qaphla - [Create a select list in half-hour increments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247229/create-a-select-list-in-half-hour-increments-in-python))

```
[((str(i / 60 % 24 + 1) if (i / 60 % 24 + 1) > 9 else "0" + str(i / 60 % 24 + 1)) + ":" + (str(i % 60) if i % 60 > 9 else "0" + str(i % 60)) ) for i in xrange(0, 1360, 30)]
```

In template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Hour</th>
            {% for user in users %}
                <th>
                    {{ user }}
                </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for hour in hours %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ hour }}</td>
                {% for user in users %}
                    <td>

                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I do not know how to put hours of work into table. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding to your this table:

```
2015-01-02

+-------+- USER1 -+- USER2 -+- USER3 -+
| 00:30 |         |         |         |
| 01:00 | ####### |         |         |
| 01:30 | ####### |         |         |
| 02:00 | ####### | ####### |         |
| 02:30 | ####### | ####### |         |
| 03:00 |         | ####### |         |
| 03:30 |         |         |         |
| 04:00 |         |         |         |
| 04:30 |         |         |         |
| 05:00 |         |         | ####### |
| 05:30 |         |         | ####### |
| 06:00 |         |         |         |
| 06:30 |         |         |         |
| [...] |         |         |         |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I don't think you intend to make a table for each day, instead I would suggest you to use this table:

[image]

It will keep track of user in one table for each day. The model definition is like this:

```
def time_slots(*args):
    class TimeSlot(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    for slot in args[0]:
        models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    ).contribute_to_class(TimeSlot, slot)
    return TimeSlot
slots = ['%s:%s%s' % (h, m, ap) for ap in ('am', 'pm') for h in ([12] + [x for x in range(1,12)]) for m in ('00', '30')]
class UserTableSlot(time_slots(slots)):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Well, if you intend to enter value to the table manually, then it will be really a lot of hassle. Instead using [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will be a preferable option.

For example, if you use celery's [periodic task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), then everyday at 12am, you can get all the user login information of previous day and input it in the table like this:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour=0))
def update_user_time_slots():
        for user in Users.objects.all():
             for item in LoginLogout.objects.filter(user=user, t_login__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)):
                  slots = ['%s:%s%s' % (h, m, ap) for ap in ('am', 'pm') for h in ([12] + [x for x in range(1,12)]) for m in ('00', '30')]
                  for s in slots:
                      if time.strptime(s, "%I:%M") > time.strptime((item.t_login.strftime('%H:%M')),'%H:%M'):
                           t_slot, _is_created = UserTimeSlot.objects.get_or_create(user=user, date=datetime.datetime.now().date())
                           if time.strptime(s, "%I:%M") < time.strptime((item.t_logout.strftime('%H:%M')),'%H:%M'):
                                 break
                            setattr(t_slot, s, True)
```